# Attaching file to an email in python leads to a blank file name?

Tags: python, email, filenames, attachment

The following snipit of code works fine, except for the fact that the resulting attachment file name is blank in the email (the file opens as 'noname' in gmail). What am I doing wrong?

```
file_name = RecordingUrl.split("/")[-1]
            file_name=file_name+ ".wav"
            urlretrieve(RecordingUrl, file_name)

            # Create the container (outer) email message.
            msg = MIMEMultipart()
            msg['Subject'] = 'New feedback from %s (%a:%a)' % (
From, int(RecordingDuration) / 60, int(RecordingDuration) % 60)

            msg['From'] = "noreply@example.info"
            msg['To'] = 'user@gmail.com'
            msg.preamble = msg['Subject']                
            file = open(file_name, 'rb')
            audio = MIMEAudio(file.read())
            file.close()
            msg.attach(audio)

            # Send the email via our own SMTP server.
            s = smtplib.SMTP()
            s.connect()
            s.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], msg.as_string())
            s.quit()
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to add a [Content-Disposition header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Content-Disposition) to the `audio` part of the message using the [`add_header` method](http://docs.python.org/library/email.message.html#email.message.Message.add_header):

```
file = open(file_name, 'rb')
audio = MIMEAudio(file.read())
file.close()
audio.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=file_name)
msg.attach(audio)
```

Comment: Thank you. This is the third adaptation I've had to do to make python email examples workable, they really need to be re-written.

Comment: @Sean W. - `add_header` is used in this example: http://docs.python.org/library/email-examples.html#id2